# Joining two tables and then fetching n% of the rows randomly from the result. (Querying the tables in http://data.stackexchange.com/ )

Tags: sql-server, optimization

I am trying to fetch a random sample of 1% of resultant rows after joining two tables (users and posts) from the stackoverflow data dump (**https://data.stackexchange.com/**).

I used the following query:

```
select top 1 percent * from users u join posts p ON p.OwnerUserId = u.Id 
order by newid();
```

Due to some server constraints on execution time, I am getting the error:

> Error: "Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding."

Can somebody suggest me on how to optimize the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When selecting random data from a large table, newid() isn't really a good option because it requires all the rows to be sorted -- and if only 1 percent is selected, that's a lot of wasted time.

Microsoft has recommended to use `binary_checksum` to [select rows randomly](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc441928.aspx), and if the accuracy of 1% isn't important, this should work a lot better:

```
select * from Users u
join (
  select * from Posts
  WHERE (ABS(CAST(
    (BINARY_CHECKSUM
    (Id, NEWID())) as int))
    % 100) < 1
) p on p.OwnerUserId = u.Id
```

Since posts is a view, it's not possible to use [tablesample](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189108%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), but in a real case that is an option too.

Answer (score 0):

With `rand()` you can show a random number of rows this way:

```
set @r = rand();
SELECT * FROM `anuncios` WHERE rand() < @r
```

- note that with this method you could obtain also zero records, if you want to obtain a minimum, maximum or even a specific percentage of records play setting the `r`variable to whatever you need.